# C#, integer entered not between two numbers

Tags: c#, arrays

I have to make it to when an integer entered that is not between 0 and 10 then it will display a message, whatever the number entered is not between 0 and 10. Also when -99 is entered it will exit the program. I have tried the while statement and nothing seems to be working.

```
        int total = 0;
        double avg;            
        string inValue;

        int[] score = new int[8];

        // prompt user for initial values
        for (int i = 0; i < score.Length; i++)
        {
            Write("Please enter homework score [0 to 10] (-99 to exit): \n", i + 0);
            inValue = ReadLine();
            if (int.TryParse(inValue, < 1 && > 10) == false)
                WriteLine("Integer entered, {0}, is not between 0 and 10.");
            if (int.TryParse(inValue, out score[i])
                == false)
                WriteLine("\n\tInvalid data - re-enter homework score: ");


        }
```

Comment: your trying to mix two lines `if (int.TryParse(inValue, < 1 && > 10) == false)` get the value using an out then then evauluate the if using the value

Comment: Read c# docs available everywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't put the "greater than 10, less than 1" condition *inside* the TryParse() method, it does not [support that](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx). So check the condition separately. Also no need to check `if (something == false)` because that's identical to `if (!something)`. I changed your ReadLine/Write/WriteLine's to have `Console.` prepended so it works on my system. You will need a while loop for the "please re-enter homework score" to work as you intend, but the code here does fix your original problem..

```
        int total = 0;
        double avg;
        string inValue;

        int[] score = new int[8];

        // prompt user for initial values
        for (int i = 0; i < score.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write("Please enter homework score [0 to 10] (-99 to exit): \n", i + 0);
            inValue = Console.ReadLine();
            if (int.TryParse(inValue, out score[i]))
            {
                if (score[i] == 99)
                { Environment.Exit(0); }

                bool between0and10 = score[i] <= 10 && score[i] >= 0;
                if (!between0and10)
                { Console.WriteLine("Integer entered, {0}, is not between 0 and 10."); }
            }
            else
            { Console.WriteLine("\n\tInvalid data - re - enter homework score: "); }
        }
```

Comment: Either don't use`{` and `}` for a single statement or use multi-line. It is hard to read your code....

Comment: @Eser I guess I've gotten used to it. I want the braces there to avoid that 1 in a million bug (e.g., Apple's SSL bug a few years ago), but I also don't want to use 2 newlines for them to save space. I suppose I should ask the team I'm on if it annoys them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
int total = 0;
double avg;
string inValue;

int[] score = new int[8];

// prompt user for initial values
for (int i = 0; i < score.Length; i++)
{
    Write("Please enter homework score [0 to 10] (-99 to exit): \n", i + 0);
    inValue = ReadLine();
    if (!int.TryParse(inValue, out score[i]))
    {
        WriteLine("\n\tInvalid data, StackOverflow did your homework! - re-enter homework score: ");
    }
    else if (score[i] < 1 || score[i] > 10) 
    {
        WriteLine("Integer entered, {0}, is not between 0 and 10.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int[] score = new int[8];
            string sVal;
            int val;
            int i = 0;
            while (i < score.Length)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Please enter homework score [0 to 10] (-99 to exit):");
                sVal = Console.ReadLine();
                if (int.TryParse(sVal, out val))
                {
                    //if quit
                    if (val == -99)
                        break;

                    //if valid range
                    if (val >= 0 && val <= 10) 
                    {
                        score[i] = val;
                        i++;
                    }
                    else //invalid input range
                        Console.WriteLine("Invalid data - re-enter homework score:");
                }
                else //not a number
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid data - re-enter homework score:");
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int total = 0;
double avg;
int parsedScore;
//this bool will tell us if the data entered is valid
bool isValid;
int[] score = new int[8];
string inValue;
// prompt user for initial values
for (int i = 0; i < score.Length; i++)
    {
        Console.Write("Please enter homework score [0 to 10] (-99 to exit): \n", i + 0);
        inValue = Console.ReadLine();
        //here we check that the data entered is valid and set our bool to the result
       isValid = int.TryParse(inValue, out parsedScore);
        if (isValid && parsedScore == -99) //check first if it is -99 and then exit if need be.
        {
            System.Environment.Exit(0);
        }
        //if it is not valid we are going to prompt them to re-enter their number 
        if(!isValid || (parsedScore < 0 && parsedScore > 10))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Integer not entered or {0}, is not between 0 and 10.", inValue);
            i--; //we decrement i in order to let them re-enter at this index
        }
        else
        {
            //valid number, do logic here.
        }
```